# "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" when connecting to MySQL database via SSH.NET tunnel in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ssh, ssh.net

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL DB running on Ubuntu using C# and SSH.Net.

Our MySQL DB only allows connections from a webserver and going by what I can see from the code below, the client object connects to the webserver and then I open a port to map to 3306 on the DB server. Finally the `MySQLConnection` object opens a connection to the MySQL DB.

However I get with exception in `sql.Open()` statement:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

I've checked other threads on the same subject and tried their suggestions, but none of them seem to help me.

- [Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124040/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts)
- [Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655669/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts)
- [unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618720/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts)

and many more.

Here is some test code that I'm using -

```
var ci =
     new ConnectionInfo(
         "server", "userid", new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("userid", "userpwd"));
using (var client = new SshClient(ci))
{
    client.Connect();
    if (client.IsConnected) //This part works fine - I can connect to my Webserver.
    {
        //not sure if this is correct in our context.
        var local = new ForwardedPortDynamic("127.0.0.1",3306); 
        client.AddForwardedPort(local);
        try
        {
            local.Start();
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {

        }
        string connStr =
            "Server = dbserver;Port = 3306;Database = dbname;Uid = dbuserid;Pwd = dbpwd;";
        MySqlConnection sql = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

        try
        {
            sql.Open();
            local.Stop();
        }
        catch (MySqlException se)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

All of the credentials I've put in my code was taken off a working MySQLWorkbench connection to the MySQL DB.

I work exclusively in a Windows environment, so if you want me to check for something on the Ubuntu server please also tell me, if possible, how to check for it.

Comment: Please check and make sure of the following: is the server name correct? is the server reachable by host-name (i.e. can the host be resolved)? Is the port correct? Is the firewall open? Is the server running? Is the username valid? Is the password valid?

Comment: So, what happens when you connect with ssh directly with `ssh -L 3306:dbHostName:3306 sshuser@sshhostnameorip` then try to connect to localhost:3306?

Comment: Could be many things, have you checked the dbserver firewall?

Comment: I use SQLWorkbench to connect to the MySQLDB and all the data I've plugged into the code is based off of my SQLWorkbench connection.
I can connect using SQLWorkbench to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting via an SSH tunnel.

So your primary problem is that the `Host` in the connection string must be `localhost` (the local end of the SSH tunnel), not `dbserver`. Or even better, use `ForwardedPort.boundHost` (and `ForwardedPort.boundPort`).

---

The second problem is that you cannot use `ForwardedPortDynamic`, but `ForwardedPortLocal`.

---

```
var forwardedPort = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1", 3306);

client.AddForwardedPort(forwardedPort);
forwardedPort.Start();

string connStr =
    string.Format(
        "Server = {0};Port = {1};Database = dbname;Uid = dbuserid;Pwd = dbpwd;",
        forwardedPort.BoundHost, forwardedPort.BoundPort);
```

---

See also [Connection to MySQL from .NET using SSH.NET Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32603982/850848#32605335).

---

If your database does not run on the webserver, but on `dbhost`, you have to use that in the `ForwardedPortLocal` constructor:

```
var forwardedPort = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", "dbhost", 3306);
```